# Axapta: Find table by name in AOT

Tags: axapta, x++, aot

I would like to query the AOT to see if a table name exists using X++.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some sample code for doing that?

If table exists with the name (str tableName) provided, return true; else, return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [tableName2Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa869230.aspx) function.  It will return 0 if the table name isn't valid.

```
boolean IsValidTable(str _tableName)
{
    return tableName2Id(_tableName)==0 ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: the `? false : true` part is rather superfluous...you could just change the `==0` to `!=0`

Comment: @CaffGeek     info(strfmt("%1",IsValidTable("MyTable"))); // will return different results, depending on using Jay Hofacker's suggestion or yours. Logically it will probably make no difference, but in some contexts it might. I'd stick to Jay Hofacker's version. Hooray for AX' type system's conciseness

Comment: @slaursen What possible variable could change that? You either get a 0 or not...I just inverted the boolean logic so it was clearer.

Comment: My code dumps either "false" or "0" to the infolog. In most situations it makes no difference, but if you're writing, say, code that exports to a CSV file it would make a difference if it writes "false" or "0".